# Agent continuously poling openam

Tags: openam, cross-domain-policy, opensso

As found in openam document it says that either openam notifies about changes happened in policies and session, or agent should poll, either of the two should happen, also agent calles the sessionservice during the session validation and register a listener for notification about changes, later openam notifies the agentapp about the changes, but I can figure out from the log that their is a continuouse polling happening from agent to openam,even though I have deployed the agentapp.war which is receiving notification

"GET /openam/namingservice HTTP/1.1" 404 991

```
[19/Jan/2014:10:51:47 +0530] "GET /openam/namingservice HTTP/1.1" 200 991
[19/Jan/2014:10:51:51 +0530] "GET /openam/namingservice HTTP/1.1" 200 17
[19/Jan/2014:10:51:53 +0530] "GET /openam/namingservice HTTP/1.1" 200 991
[19/Jan/2014:10:51:54 +0530] "GET /openam/namingservice HTTP/1.1" 200 991
[19/Jan/2014:10:51:54 +0530] "GET /openam/namingservice HTTP/1.1" 200 991
[19/Jan/2014:10:51:57 +0530] "GET /openam/namingservice HTTP/1.1" 200 991
[19/Jan/2014:11:03:49 +0530] "POST /openam/sessionservice HTTP/1.1" 200 2042
[19/Jan/2014:11:03:49 +0530] "POST /openam/loggingservice HTTP/1.1" 200 183
[19/Jan/2014:11:03:49 +0530] "POST /openam/sessionservice HTTP/1.1" 200 2042
```

and the polling for the namingservice i.e:

```
[19/Jan/2014:10:51:54 +0530] "GET /openam/namingservice HTTP/1.1" 200 991
```

happens even if I don't access any application.

Can anyone help me out with the reason for such polling and is it possible to stop such polling.I wonder is it because of I selected centralized option for agent?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The agent tries to find out the specific service endpoints (URLs) for each user session specifically, hence it's fireing a namingRequest, see debug detailed debug logs

Comment: #Bernhard can this call be locally configured in agent?

Comment: or called once and cached in local?

Comment: because I see this polling happening even though I am not accessing any application,my agent name is "amadmin" same as openam admin